# Alternatives/Competitors to RWWGuard 2008

Tags: remote-access, windows-sbs-2008

Does anyone know of any alternatives or competitors to RWWGuard?

http://www.scorpionsoft.com/products/rwwguard2008/

I am looking for a two factor authentication system for Remote Web Workplace for Small Business Server 2008.  RWWGuard seems good but a little expensive and also I'd like something to evaluate it against.

Answer (score 1):

If your SBS is behind a firewall then check for any two factor auth solutions supported by the firewall.

RSA SecurID is one alternative that you can evaluate against.  It's not cheap either, but plenty of features to compare.

Comment: Thanks, any idea of a couple of the least expensive firewalls supported are?

Comment: I don't know of any firewall with built-in two factor auth.  I meant that if you already have a firewall in place, then you might be able to use it as the point of authentication.  For example if using ISA Server to reverse proxy RWW then there are products that can integrate there.